# find multiple data from multiple databases

Tags: mysql

i want to find 7 data (FM,DC,BC,MD,AT,FR,ZP) from 70 database, and to do that i need to select each database as default schema, and then have to search single data at a time, is there anyway to find all data together, or any other way? or any easy trick.

here, actually what i am doing to search data from database by database.
as i click `start search`, it find data from all tables from single database, and return tablename, columnname, and number of data found. and i need to mention that where data found.

[image]

Comment: What's the output? What do you expect and what are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need select from table with same structure but in different database you can use union for distinct value or union all for all the value

```
 select FM,DC,BC,MD,AT,FR,ZP 
 from db1.table1
 union all 
 select FM,DC,BC,MD,AT,FR,ZP 
 from db2.table2
 select FM,DC,BC,MD,AT,FR,ZP 
 from db3.table3
 union all 
 select FM,DC,BC,MD,AT,FR,ZP 
 from db4.table4
 union all 
 ..........
 select FM,DC,BC,MD,AT,FR,ZP 
 from dbN.tableN
```

Comment: in each database, around 500 tables, and i want to find data match scenario (as i mentioned way, i get tablename, and columnname, and i have to mention that table and column name where record found)

Comment: explain better , update your question  with a more clear sample  please ..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UNION` to merge the tables from all the databases. To see where the results came from, you can add additional columns with literals that identify it.

```
SELECT "db1" AS whichDB, "table1" AS whichTable, FM,DC,BC,MD,AT,FR,ZP 
FROM db1.table1
WHERE <conditions>
UNION ALL
SELECT "db2" AS whichDB, "table2" AS whichTable, FM,DC,BC,MD,AT,FR,ZP 
FROM db2.table2
WHERE <conditions>
SELECT "db3" AS whichDB, "table3" AS whichTable, FM,DC,BC,MD,AT,FR,ZP 
FROM db3.table3
WHERE <conditions>
...
```